# error while rails s, and i have nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': 
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/MyRubyBlog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `bundler` gem with the following command.

```
gem install bundler
```

Hope,this will help you.

Comment: Also make use of a Gemfile and run `bundle install`. Installing bundler it self wont help much ;)